# Select Meshes from Scene Collection without relying on name

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I need to select Meshes from a Scene Collection and I'm hoping that there's a better way than doing it by string matching. Here's my Scene Collection with my Meshes. The 'Vert' meshes are meshes with only 1 vert:

[image: Scene collection]

This code finds the 'Vert' meshes in a collection using `startswith()` for string recognition:

```
import bpy

print('printing objects in scene')
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects: 
    print('obj.name is:', obj.name, 'obj is:', obj, 'obj.type is', obj.type)
    if obj.name.startswith('Vert'): 
        print('found vert:', obj.name)
```

I'm eventually planning to add meshes with an operator, so the names will be standardized, but this method feels sloppy. Is there a better way?

Comment: Hard to know based on info in question, is the "Vert" mesh a mesh with only one vert?

Comment: A bit confusing to use the term 'Vert' here as they are both meshes.

Comment: It appears that the Vert is a mesh with only one vert.  I generated them with Add>Mesh>Single Vert

Comment: IIRC from the `add mesh extra objects addon`?.   Could you please edit this detail into question

Answer (score 0):

**By vert count**

If they are still single vert meshes could also look for a single vert count.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context

single_vert_obs = [o for o 
        in context.scene.objects
        if o.type == 'MESH'
        and len(o.data.vertices) == 1]
```